# Where I can find a hierarchy chart for .Net framework 4 or silverlight classes?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0

I found a hierarchy chart for .net framework 3.5 at [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/netfxbcl/thread/7360198f-1163-4651-8093-0cb68f56dd97). Does anyone know where I can find the same chart for .net framework 4 or silverlight ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one .NET4:

- [.NET Framework 4 and Extensions](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A8A715-7695-493C-8CFA-8E0C23A4BE1D/098-115952-NETFX4-Poster.pdf)

found here:

- [Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Commonly Used Types & Namespaces](http://dotnetassociates.blogspot.com/2011/02/microsoft-net-framework-commonly-used.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. I had seen something wrong at first glance. The first link is what I want.